# Async Stack Traces in Node.js 14.15.0

Tags: node.js, async-await, callstack

Based on the documentation I would assume that Node.js 14 does now support stack traces in async code but unfortunately using `node --async-stack-traces test.js` still generates only a partial stack trace and I would be most interested to understand why.

Running the following code:

```js
main()

function main() {
    sub();
}

async function sub() {
    console.trace('before sleep');
    await delay(1000);
    console.trace('after sleep');
}

function delay(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => resolve(), ms);
    });
}
```

shows the complete stack before but only a partial stack after using `await`:

```sh
~/MyDev/doberkofler/test $ node test.js
Trace: before sleep
    at sub (/Users/doberkofler/MyDev/doberkofler/test/test.js:10:10)
    at main (/Users/doberkofler/MyDev/doberkofler/test/test.js:6:2)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/doberkofler/MyDev/doberkofler/test/test.js:3:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
Trace: after sleep
    at sub (/Users/doberkofler/MyDev/doberkofler/test/test.js:12:10)
~/MyDev/doberkofler/test $
```

Comment: If I had to guess, I'd say it will output the trace from the last time you called `console.trace`, worth testing out

Comment: If you remove the first `console.trace` there is still no stack on the seconds one.

Answer (score 10):

Async stack traces will work, but only for an unbroken chain of async methods. So to fix your example, make your main method async, and then await the call to sub.

If you use promises, or miss an await before return then it will break.

This is explained here: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/36126#issuecomment-827023528

> This is not as much a bug as it is just a limitation of the [zero-cost async stack traces mechanism](https://cloudreports.net/v8-zero-cost-async-stack-traces/) implemented by v8.
>
> Specifically, let's look at the original example:
>
> ```js
> main()
>
> function main() {
>     sub();
> }
>
> async function sub() {
>     console.trace('before sleep');
>     await delay(1000);
>     console.trace('after sleep');
> }
>
> function delay(ms) {
>     return new Promise(resolve => {
>         setTimeout(() => resolve(), ms);
>     });
> }
> ```
>
> The `main` is a regular synchronous function. It calls `sub()` which triggers `console.trace('before sleep')` *synchronously* within the scope of `main()`'s callstack. That is why `before sleep` contains the full stack trace information. What happens next is that `main()`'s callstack unwinds before the microtask queue later triggers the `console.trace('after sleep')`. By the time the second `console.trace()` is called, `main()` callstack is long gone and information about it no longer exists for v8 to do anything about it. While `sub()` *looks* like it's a single callstack, it's actually several spread out over time.
>
> In order for `after sleep` to get the full stack trace, the caller of `sub()` *has* to be an async function and the call to `sub()` *has* to use await. For instance:
>
> ```js
> main()
>
> async function main() {
>     await sub();
> }
>
> async function sub() {
>     console.trace('before sleep');
>     await delay(1000);
>     console.trace('after sleep');
> }
>
> function delay(ms) {
>     return new Promise(resolve => {
>         setTimeout(() => resolve(), ms);
>     });
> }
> ```
>
> How does this change things? Well, making `main()` async and having it `await sub()` means that v8 must retain the callstack information for `main()` until `sub()` completes -- that is, the full callstack information for `main()` will still be resident in memory and easily available to v8. When the second call to `console.trace()` occurs (and it creates the internal `Error` object used to generate the printed stack, all of the callstack details will be readily at hand and a proper error stack that goes *only* back to the top-most async function using `await`  is generated:
>
> ```
> Trace: before sleep
>     at sub (/root/node/tmp/f.js:8:13)
>     at main (/root/node/tmp/f.js:4:10)
>     at Object.<anonymous> (/root/node/tmp/f.js:1:1)
>     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1108:14)
>     at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1137:10)
>     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:988:32)
>     at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:828:14)
>     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:76:12)
>     at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47
> Trace: after sleep
>     at sub (/root/node/tmp/f.js:10:13)
>     at async main (/root/node/tmp/f.js:4:4)
> ```
>
> The bottom line is that it absolutely is not a bug. The async stack traces mechanism is working exactly as it is designed to work -- it's just limited in what information it can capture. Now, whether that can be improved upon or not is a secondary discussion, but there is no bug in Node.js here as we are relying entirely on what v8 is providing to us here.

Answer (score 2):

This problem might be a bug in v8: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/36126